# Android SQLite not deleting row by id

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to delete a row given a specific id and see the update reflected in my listview, but the row is not deleted. The same process works for `update`, but not delete. Here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
...

@Override
    public void onPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, int which) {

            //Shared Preferences
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(EditLog.PREF_FILENAME, 0);
            long id = 0;
            String date = "";
            String hours = "";
            String lessonType = "";
            String weatherCondition = "";
            if (!(pref == null)) {
                id = pref.getLong("rowId", 0);
                date = pref.getString("date", "");
                hours = pref.getString("hours", "");
                lessonType = pref.getString("lessonType", "");
                weatherCondition = pref.getString("weatherCondition", "");
            }

            if (which == 2) {
                LessonLogDBHelper dbhelp = new LessonLogDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();
                db.delete(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
            } else {
                LessonLogDBHelper dbhelp = new LessonLogDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();
                final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_DATE, date);
                values.put(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_HOURS, hours);
                values.put(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_LESSON_TYPE, lessonType);
                values.put(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_WEATHER, weatherCondition);
                db.update(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=" + id, null);

            }

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, new DrivingLog());
            transaction.commit();

    }

...
```

If which == 2, that means the user clicked on the `delete` button, the id (in the db) of the item clicked is passed, and I call `delete`. This process works for update, but not delete.

EDIT: Neat things

Something weird I found is that if I try to `update` an entry, then I will be delete **any single entry** from the db. If I don't try to update first, then I can't.

Here is my table def:

LessonLogContract

```
package com.example.name.drivinglessona3;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.StringBuilderPrinter;

public class LessonLogContract {
    private LessonLogContract() {}

    public static class LogEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "lesson";
        public static final String CN_DATE = "date";
        public static final String CN_HOURS = "hours";
        public static final String CN_LESSON_TYPE = "lesson_type";
        public static final String CN_WEATHER = "weather";
    }
}
```

LessonLogDBHelper

```
package com.example.name.drivinglessona3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class LessonLogDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    LessonLogContract.LogEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_DATE+ " TEXT," +
                    LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_HOURS+ " TEXT," +
                    LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_LESSON_TYPE+ " TEXT," +
                    LessonLogContract.LogEntry.CN_WEATHER + " TEXT)";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LogEntry.db";

    public LessonLogDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**

When I was clicking my delete button, I wasn't saving `_id` to SharedPreferences, so in `MainActivity` I was getting the wrong value of id.

Comment: Do you know if db.delete is actually being called?

Comment: yeah it is being called

Comment: R u sure your item clicked Id is passed..???....and also leave  space here....." _id = ? "

Comment: Yes it is being passed

Comment: Very weird: If I update the entry, and then try to delete it, it works.

Comment: and i think there is no need to....Long.toString(id)....can you pass only id without  convertion to Long.

Comment: it seems there is no mistakes in your code....try to put your delete code into one sppecific method...and see your deleted Id....
Like

Comment: long DeletedId = db.delete(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)});

Comment: try this. db.delete(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME, "_id= ?"+id, null);

Comment: @KeyurThumar `"_id= ?"+id,` it makes no sense at all

Comment: I think ago meant `db.delete(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME, "_id= "+id, null);` i.e. same as the update that works.

Comment: what is the definition of the table `LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME`? how did you create that table?

Comment: check if any log is printed..and how are you sure that it is not deleted? just because Recyclerview is not updated? check if problem is with updating the Recyclerview ..

Comment: The problem isn't with the view

Comment: @pskink public string defined in LessonLogContract.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @pskink Figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Just change **String.valueOf()**  instead of Long.toString() in delete Line. 
That means replace db.delete() line with below code:

```
db.delete(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

I hope this method work for u.

Comment: @JeremyFisher Then may be you have to try `db.delete(LessonLogContract.LogEntry.TABLE_NAME, "_id="+id+"", null);` code. Because I think when there is a Integer  or double type comparison it is better to compare directly instead of  convert & compare in string..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public void delete(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("MST_Item", "ItemID=" + id, null);
        db.close();
}
```

Comment: coding `db.close();` may cause issues if the calling method expects the database to still be open.

Comment: What is MST_Item?

Comment: Ya MST_Item is the table name from the database.

Comment: Putting `close` doesn't seem to make a difference. The one behavior I notice is that If I click on my update button first, even if I don't really update, then I will be able to delete one thing.